# What kind of decking doesn't have gaps to catch debris?

Tags: deck

The gaps in my deck are routinely jammed with "helicopter" poplar seeds, which lodge with the hard seed just above the gap.  The "blade" of the seed anchors them so firmly that no blower or pressure washer can dislodge many of them.  The only way to get them out is to scrape them with a hook-like blade.

Is there any decking style or installation method that is immune to this problem?  (I'm not sure if the "obvious" solution of installing the planks with 1/4" gaps is good.)

[image: Seeds in deck cracks]

Comment: ... can you blow from below?

Comment: Or vacuum with a yard vac from above?  I have a electric blower/vacuum/mulcher that works quite well in general; might work for this.  It will vacuum up leaves but not rocks.

Comment: Yes, here in Maple country we often install decking with 5/16" to 3/8" gaps.

Comment: @MarkStewart and Daniel:  I've tried blowing from below and used the vacuum mode of an electric blower from above.  Both leave a large number of seeds stuck in there, I think because once they're in a crack the exposed surface area of the seed is very small from any accessible angle.

Comment: Why are you against widening the gap?

Comment: @psaxton – If that works well I could do that.  I just assumed that widening past a certain point would start to let bugs setup shop in the gaps, which would be just as uncomfortable for people who want to walk or relax on the deck.

Comment: I'm more surprised that you *don't* have a gap, as the gap had been the recommendation for all decking I've ever seen.

Comment: A home inspector once advised me to take a circular saw (“skil saw”) and widen the gaps.

Comment: Use a regular hand saw from the top, possibly.

Comment: They look more like sycamore seeds to me, but that doesn't help your problem!

Comment: This question doesn't ask how to clean out the slots. It asks about alternative products. It's a shopping question.

Comment: And cutting plastic decking with a handsaw sounds like legit torture.

Comment: @whiskeychief Maybe even try a router, then you could even round the edges while widening the gap.

Comment: ... Put down outdoor carpeting and vacuum that periodically? (Bugs "setting up shop in the gaps" seems unlikely; they have no particular reason to do so.)

Answer (score 5):

I use a heavy-duty paper clip opened up to make hooks on each end, then attach one end of that paper clip to the (smaller) hose of my shop vac with duct tape. (The hook on this end keeps the paper clip from spinning around.) I usually attach it to the top of the hose so the second end of the paper clip points down to make a hook. Then I turn on the shop vac and drag the hook through the gap to dislodge the seeds, which the shop vac sucks up through the hose. The problem is that the paper clips break fairly easily so you have to be careful/go slowly. Although it takes a fair number of paper clips (about 5 to 10 for my 14' x 20' deck) that beats having to bend over (or sit on your butt) with a putty knife to pull them out or push them through. And blasting them through with the power washer damages the edges of the decking, which (based on my neighbor's deck) makes the wood decay faster.

Comment: Good idea.  Re breaking the clips, try using a [cheap](https://www.harborfreight.com/8-inch-linoleum-knife-92552.html) linoleum knife.  Grind the blade down a bit to make it less sharp so it won't cut the deck and give it a bit more of a hook. Cut slits in the handle for attachment to your hose.

Answer (score 3):

Use a butter knife and push them through the gaps

Answer (score 0):

I use my power washer's narrowest spray tip and blast them through